# Access Objective-C variable from C++ function

Tags: c++, iphone

I'm working on a project that just needs to be rewritten but that is not an option at this point.

I have a C++ function that is called and does all kinds of stuff.  I need it to read a variable from the App Delegate class.

For example I have:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
    UIWindow *window;
    MyViewController *viewController;

 int mToleranceLevel;
}
```

I then have a function that needs to access the mToleranceLevel:

```
bool FindExtrinsics(...)
{
 float maxError = mainDelegate.mMaxError;
        ...
}
```

The problem is that this was declared like so:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController 
{
  ...
}

@properties ...

bool FindExtrinsics(...);

@end
```

So how would I get a value from the AppDelegate class.  I do know how to get the current delegate:

```
mainDelegate = (RedStripeARAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

But how do I use this info to get the value in my C++ function.  Is there a way to make a static variable so I can call MyAppDelegate.mToleranceValue;??

Comment: AppDelegate *aD = ((AppDelegate*)CCApplication::sharedApplication());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode supports `Objective-C++`, which enables you to use Objective-C calls from C++ code. Change the extension of your C++ code file from .cpp (or .cc) to **.mm** and you'll be able to get the value from your C++ code just as you would from Objective-C code.

Comment: well I could NOT access from C++ function next variable: `@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FrameProcessEvents> delegate;`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the compiler and runtime, an Objective C object is usually just a pointer to a struct, and an instance variable may simply be a member of that C struct.  And C syntax is a proper subset of Objective C.  So your object variable access from C or C++ may be as simple as:

```
if (myObject != NULL) {
    x = myObject->myInstanceVariable;
}
```

Comment: Considering you need to include the Objective-C interface in your C++ code if you want this to work, you'll need Objective-C++ anyways, so you might want use the regular accessors as well.